# Writing a program that asks for a input and encodes it as the numeric code for each letter using the ord function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that asks for a input, and encodes it as the numeric code for each letter using the ord function.

I am struggling to get it to repeat for each letter;

My current code can only get it to print the first letter in ord, but not sure how to do it for every letter.

```
message = "Doughnuts"
length = len(message)

while message:
  l = list(message)
  print(ord(l[0])) 
  break
```

My answer is outputting only one like this

```
Dessert idea: Doughnuts
68
```

Except it needs to output all of the encryption like this

```
Dessert idea: Doughnuts
68 111 117 103 104 110 117 116 115
```

having a space between each result.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each character as such using `for`.

```
for character in message:
    print(ord(character))
```

Or if you want to keep with a `while`.

```
i = 0
while i < len(message):
    print(ord(message[i]))
    i += 1
```

---

Note that if you want all of the numbers to be on the same line, cast the ordered value to a string, add a space to each printed number and the `end` attribute set to an empty string. Building off of the first example:

```
print(str(ord(character)) + ' ', end='')
```

Comment: is there anyway I can stop it printing in new lines everytime, I need it to print with a space between each result.

Comment: Okay, but can directly do `end=' '` instead of adding `' '` then `end=''`, as in my answer

Comment: Either works. Doing `end=' '` doesn't require a cast to string whereas `end=''` does to have a space in-between.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on python 2, put:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

In the top of the code.

Why not:

```
message = "Doughnuts"
for i in message:
   print(ord(i),end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm Doing Grok too!

Here's what I did for this question.

```
hi = input('Dessert idea: ')
output = ''
for i in hi:
  i = str(ord(i))+ ' '
  output += i
print(output[:-1])
```

Hope this helped :D